# Looking for an intuitive approach of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I started reading up on the topics of differential equations and tried to solve certain problems to get used to those kind of equations, in particular I tried to understand every "$=$" and "$\Rightarrow$". 
However I soon stumbled over this equation:

$ {1 \over y} * { dx \over dy } - {x \over y^2}   = y $

or: $ {d \over dy} ( {x \over y} ) = y $

Now I am trying to understand why: $ {1 \over y} * { dx \over dy } - {x \over y^2} = {d \over dy} ( {x \over y} ) $
In particular I am confused how to interpret those two terms, how to interpret them:

${d \over dy} ( {x \over y} ) $ and $ { dx \over dy } $ ;

I would be happy, if someone could help me and might recommend a detailed read about differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

This is really just the quotient rule:

$$\frac{d}{dy} \left ( \frac{x}{y} \right ) = \frac{y \frac{dx}{dy}-x}{y^2} = \frac{1}{y} \frac{dx}{dy} - \frac{x}{y^2}.$$

Here $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$, while $\frac{d}{dy} \left ( \frac{x}{y} \right )$ is the derivative of $\frac{x}{y}$ with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ depends on $y$.

So :

$$\frac{d}{dy} \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)=\frac{d}{dy} \left( x \cdot \frac{1}{y} \right)=\frac{dx}{dy} \cdot \frac{1}{y}+x \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{1}{y} \right)=\frac{dx}{dy} \cdot \frac{1}{y}+x \left(-\frac{1}{y^2} \right)$$